# Closing turtle Graphics GUI while operation

Tags: python, user-interface, turtle-graphics

I wrote a python script for drawing a circle of squares.

```
import turtle
angle = 0
turn_ang = 30
while (angle <= 360):
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.right(turn_ang)
    angle = angle + turn_ang
turtle.done()
```

I want to be able to close the turtle GUI while it is still in the process of drawing, i.e., when the while loop is running. If I click on close, the GUI says 'Not Responding'. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't reproduce your problem on my system, I've a suggestion that might fix your issue.  As currently designed, your program completely runs before you turn over control to the main loop, i.e. everthing gets drawn before you call `turtle.done()` which is when the turtle starts listening for events like the window closing.

Let's take another approach where your drawing code happens ***after*** you call `turtle.done()` (or `turtle.exitonclick()` in my example) by putting it on an event timer:

```
import turtle

angle = 0
TURN_ANGLE = 30

def square():
    global angle

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.right(TURN_ANGLE)
    angle += TURN_ANGLE

    if angle <= 360:
        turtle.ontimer(square, 100)
    else:
        turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.ontimer(square, 100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Let us know if that solves your immediate issue.  Note that I've tweaked your code a bit: some things to make it work better as a timer event; some things simply because they cried out for it...